# exception http.client en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, http

Estoy intentando manejar excepciones tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection (site, timeout = 5)
```

cuando excede el tiempo de espera ¿Qué excepción debería usar?

```
try:
            conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(site, timeout=5)
            conn.request("GET", "/")
        except http.client.NotConnected as e:
            cprint("%-30s %-50s %-10s %-30s %-20s" %(time.strftime("%c"),site, st,rs,elapse_time),'red')
```

Nunca he manejado excepciones y requiero que no se detenga cuando un sitio web no responda dentro del timeout.

el código es el siguiente

```
while 1:
    cantT=0
    for site in SITES:
            #prueba
            #conn = urllib.request.urlopen(site)
            #conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(site, timeout=10)
            #Variables de conexion y estado
        try:
            conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(site, timeout=5)
            conn.request("GET", "/")
            response = conn.getresponse()
            rs = response.reason
            st = str (response.status)
            cantT+= 1
            #se calcula el tiempo transcurido para el check
            inicio = time.time()
            elapse_time = str(time.time()-inicio)
            if response.status == 200:
                cprint("%-30s %-50s %-10s %-30s %-20s" %(time.strftime("%c"),site, st,rs,elapse_time),'green')
```

y en la documentacion no es que diga mucho.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

se requería usar la siguiente excepcion como la de urllib.
except (http.client.HTTPException, socket.timeout, socket.error):

Answer (score 1):

La excepción que se retorna cuando se supera el timeout viene hereda de `socket`: [**`socket.timeout`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.timeout)

```
import  http.client
import socket


try:
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(site, timeout=5)
    conn.request("GET", "/")
    # ...
except socket.timeout:
    # Manejo de la excepción
    print("Tiempo excedido")
```

Comment: Gracias, me funciono de la siguiente manera: http.client.HTTPException, socket.timeout, socket.error